# 'Name not resolved' error in API fetch function

Tags: javascript, windows, fetch

I wrote the following code to fetch data from an API:

```
fetch("https://crossorigin.me/https://swapi.co/api/people/1")
.then(response => response.json())
.then(data => console.log(data))
```

unforunately, it threw this error:

> GET https://crossorigin.me/https://swapi.co/api/people/1 net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

The API has no cross origin restrictions, however, it still throws an error without the cross origin bypass, so I am forced to use it. i watched a couple of tutorials and even used exactly same code as their, but i still get same error.

Comment: https://crossorigin.me is not a registered domain name, so I'm not quite sure where you got it. https://swapi.co/api/ also appears to not be in service which is why you're receiving the error in the first place. Check for any typos in the domains.

Comment: got it, saw many instances where crossorigin.me was used thats why i tried it in the first place

Answer (score 0):

The domain crossorigin.me has probably expired and the owner has not renewed it. It was not even production-ready according to the author.
Try using https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/ or https://enable-cors.org/index.html

Comment: Tried it out, seems to solve the issue, thanks a lot